# Repulsive force on electrons in a wire carrying a current

Tags: electromagnetism

If you connect a simple circuit, you will get some current flowing through the wires. Current is just a flow of charged particles. Will these charged particles making up the current experience a coloumb force? If so do we ever talk about it since I haven’t heard this being discussed in any of my electric circuit lectures.

Comment: If the electrons were not affected by a coulomb force, how would they move in the conductor?

Comment: I am referring to the coloumb force due to the adjacent charges moving in a wire carrying current, on a given charge. Do these internal forces just cancel?